# VBA Excel - Checking Text Similarity in Same Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

I am trying to check for text similarity for the text in the "Line-Side Loc" in Column J. **If the text in column J isn't the same, I would like a thick bottom border applied from columns A-J** to annunciate the difference. If the text is the same, I would like it to be a thin line. Image 1 is what it looks like currently when the macro ends. Ideally, it would look like Image 2.

This is my code and where I would like to insert the new code to add the thick lines
[image: Code]

I do not know how to write this code. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Currently, this is what is happening. With the code I have below.
[image: Current Outcome]
[image: Current Code]

Comment: Both images look the same to me. Not sure but it looks like conditional formatting may do what you want. Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1662192/edit) to clarify things? Bear in mind we don't have access to your spreadsheet.

Comment: isn't the same as _what_? And you still haven,t explained the difference between the two images.

Comment: He wants to have a black border anytime the text above the cell in J column changes.  It is easily done with conditional formatting.

Comment: You can get a **thin** black border with conditional formatting, but if you really want a **thick** black border, you will need VBA event code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with a thin black border, then conditional formatting will work.  If you really want a **thick** black border, you will need VBA event code, since you cannot modify the thickness of a border in the conditional formatting border property.

To enter this event-triggered Macro, right click on the sheet tab.
Select "View Code" from the right-click drop-down menu.
Then paste the code below into the window that opens.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim v As Variant, I As Long
    
Set dataRange = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(100, 10)) 'change as needed
If Not Intersect(Target, dataRange) Is Nothing Then
    With dataRange
        v = .Columns(9)
        For I = 1 To UBound(v) - 1
            If v(I, 1) <> v(I + 1, 1) Then
                With .Rows(I).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Color = vbBlack
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With
            Else
                .Rows(I).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone 'or whatever you want for the default border
            End If
        Next I
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

***Edit: to have a stand-alone and not an event-triggered macro***
***enter into a regular module**
 you can then call it from another macro, or trigger it with a button, or start it manually*

```
Option Explicit
Sub LineIT()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim v As Variant, I As Long
    
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4") 'or whatever workbook and worksheet the table you which to process is located

With WS
    Set dataRange = Range(.Cells(2, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp)) 'change as needed
    With dataRange
        v = .Columns(10)
        For I = 1 To UBound(v) - 1
            If v(I, 1) <> v(I + 1, 1) Then
                With .Rows(I).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Color = vbBlack
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With
            Else
                .Rows(I).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone 'or whatever you want for the default border
            End If
        Next I
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127528/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-rosenfeld-vba-excel-checking-text-similarity-in-sa).

Answer (score 1):

This is easily accomplished with conditional formatting.

1. Make the active cell J2
2. Open up the conditional format dialog box
3. Select `Use Formula for Conditional Formatting`
4. Type in the formula `=$J2<>$J1` and set the border as you like
5. Adjust the `Applies To` cells to make the underline go to the cells you want

[image: Excel Conditional Formatting]